# mongoose sort latest document entry in db and update

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to sort the latest document matching the query then set paid property to true.

```
Payment.update({orderRef: paidRef} , {$set:{paid:true}}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){ });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) because you only want to update one.

like :

```
findOneAndUpdate({
 orderRef: paidRef,
}, {
  $set: { paid : true },
}, { 
  new: true,
  sort: { date: -1 },
});
```

with `date` a field where the creation date is stored